# Add missing dates to time series data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have a time series dataframe with yearly temperature values for multiple cities, but for a few cities I have a set of dates missing

Dataframe Example

```
ID      Date        City    PRCP    TAVG    TMAX    TMIN
abcd1   2020-01-01  Zurich  0       -1.9    -0.9    -2.9
abcd1   2020-01-02  Zurich  9.1      8.8    12.7    4.9
abcd1   2020-01-03  Zurich  0.8      8.55   13.2    3.9
abcd1   2020-01-04  Zurich  0        4.1    10.8    -2.6

.
.
abcd9   2020-01-01 Singapore 4.1    5.9     0.3     3.1
abcd9   2020-01-04 Singapore 0.32   13.78   4.22    9   
abcd9   2020-01-28 Singapore 9.42   11.32   5.34    8.33
...
```

Now suppose that a few dates are missing in every month, such that total count of days in `Date` column is 300 days. I want to add the rest of the days to dataset and assign `nulls(NaN)` to column `TMAX,TMIN..` for such dates such that total count of days is 365.

This is what I am doing right now

```
df_list = []

for (columns, group) in df.groupby(['ID', 'City']):
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([group['ID'].unique(),
                                      pd.date_range(group['Date'].min().replace(day=1), end=group['Date'].max(), freq='D')],
                                     names=['ID', 'Date'])
    group = group.set_index(['ID', 'Date']).reindex(idx).reset_index()
    group['City'] = group['City'].fillna(method='bfill')
    df_list.append(group)

data = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

What this does is fills dates between a `start_index` and an `end_index`(and fills NaN to PRCP, TMIN, TMAX, TAVG for those dates), but even with this I end up missing a few dates i.e. the count does not equal to 365.

e.g If the source file has data from 1st Oct to 28th Oct, the above will add any missing dates between this range but will not add 29,30,31 to dataset.

Is there a way I can impute all dates from `1 Jan` to `31 Dec`(year being irrelevant and ignoring leap years) for all cities in my `City` column.

Comment: What is the `ID` column (maybe `CODE`)?

Comment: @Corralien Yes, made the edit

Comment: If you don't consider year and leap years, is it possible to replace the `Date` by the `DayOfYear`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can add missing dates in the dataframe by using custom function with `DataFrame.reindex` in `GroupBy.apply` and then reassign Index:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

f = lambda x: x.reindex(pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01'), pd.to_datetime('2020-12-31'), name='date'))
df = df.set_index('Date').groupby(['ID','City']).apply(f).drop(['ID','City'], axis=1)
```

Comment: This sort of worked(with a `reset_index()`), but the rest of my columns `TMAX,TMIN...` all had NaNs i.e. entire yearly data has NaNs

Comment: Check the dtype of Date column and convert it into datetime as mentioned in first line. I got the same error earlier

Comment: Did you replace CODE with ID in your case? Here is the output https://imgur.com/a/S2UIhX5 You can accept answer if its working :)